If $\|f_1\|_{L^p} = \|f_2\|_{L^p} = \dots = \|f_n\|_{L^p} = \left\|\frac{f_1 + \dots + f_n}{n}\right\|_{L^p}$ then $f_1 = f_2 = \ldots = f_n$ a.e.

Let $f_j$, $1 \leq j \leq n$, be real-valued measurable functions on a measure space $(X, \mu)$ and suppose that
$$
\|f_1\|_{L^p} = \|f_2\|_{L^p} = \dots = \|f_n\|_{L^p} = \left\|\frac{f_1 + \dots + f_n}{n}\right\|_{L^p}
$$
for some $1 < p < \infty$. Prove that $f_1 = \dots = f_n \geq 0$ a.e. or $f_1 = \dots = f_n \leq 0$ a.e.

For every $1\le j\le n$, we have $$\left\|\frac{f_1 + \dots + f_n}{n}\right\|_{L^p} \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \|f_j\|_{L^p} = \|f_j\|_{L^p}.$$
Therefore, the condition given is the equality case in the triangle inequality for the $L^p$ norm.
If $n = 2$, this boils down to the equality case in Minkowski's inequality. If $f_1 \equiv 0$, then the conclusion is trivial. If $f_1\not\equiv 0$, then $f_1 = \lambda f_2$ a.e. for some $\lambda > 0$. The condition $\|f_1\|_{L^p} = \|f_2\|_{L^p}$ forces $\lambda = 1$. We get $f_1 = f_2$ a.e. How would you do the general case?
I suspect a typo in the exercise, i.e., $\ge 0$ and $\le 0$ conditions should be omitted since any function that changes sign would be a counterexample.
Source: Exercise $1.1.4$ in Fundamentals of Fourier Analysis by Grafakos.

maybe some extra conditions missing ? Otherwise, I don't see why this would be true. Essentially, any integrable function in $L^p$ that changes sign should be a counterexample.

The hypothesis seems to be trivially true if $f_1 = \dots = f_n$ regardless of any sign changes of the function, so this claim seems to just be false.  Where did you encounter it?

@NateEldredge This is Exercise $1.1.4$ in Fundamentals of Fourier Analysis by Grafakos.

You can also sum over the $\| f_i\|$. From the requirements, we get that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \|f_i\|_{L^p} = \left\|{f_1 + \dots + f_n}\right\|_{L^p}
$$
Now, applying Minkowski $n$-times we have that
$$\begin{align}
 &\le \left\|{f_1 }\right\|_{L^p}+\left\|{f_2 + \dots + f_n}\right\|_{L^p}
\\
 &\le\cdots
\\
&\le  \sum_{i=1}^n \|f_i\|_{L^p}
\end{align}$$
So each of the inequalities must be sharp, but that can only be if the part we pull out and the part we leave inside are non-negatively linearly dependent.
And since (non-negative) linear combinations of (non-negative) linear combinations are themselves again (non-negative) linear combinations, we get by induction that all $f_i$ are non-negative linear combinations of $f_n$.
(To be precise, we know that $f_{n-i}\in\text{span}_{\ge 0}(f_{n-i+1})$, and that $\text{span}_{\ge 0}(\text{span}_{\ge 0}(M))=\text{span}_{\ge 0}(M)$)

For the updated question about how to do induction:
Let $g= \frac1{n-1} (f_2+\cdots+ f_n)$. Then we have
$$
\Vert f_1 + (n-1) g \Vert \le \Vert f_1\Vert + (n-1) \Vert g \Vert\implies \Vert g\Vert \ge \Vert f_1\Vert.
$$
But we also have
$$
\Vert g\Vert \le \frac1{n-1} (\Vert f_2\Vert + \cdots + \Vert f_n\Vert ) = \Vert f_1\Vert.
$$
Therefore, $\Vert g\Vert = \Vert f_2\Vert = \cdots = \Vert f_n\Vert$. Now, we apply induction on $f_2,\ldots,f_n$.
